# Creating Jars without Main() method

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have downloaded a project from  SVN and have imported the same in my Eclipse IDE.The project have several .java files but none of them have any `main()` method.

It is required to make some minor changes in one of the file and then create a new version of the jar. And replace the old jar with the new version in the server.

Ours is a big project and the tool is running on Weblogic. But while creating the newer version of the jar through Eclipse ( Export>Jar) it is asking to provide the class which contains `main()` method or any entry point.

Please let me know how should I proceed to create the jar?

Comment: if that is suppose to be a runnable jar then you need to provide a main method!

Comment: You don't have to supply a main class. Export as jar, not as runnable jar.

Comment: Thanks@bekce... it worked for me !!

Comment: since the project is mounted over Weblogic server. We need to deploy it as jars and not runnable jars. https://www.quora.com/In-a-large-Java-project-how-do-I-find-where-the-class-with-the-main-method-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eclipse supports the creation of **different** JAR file types.

You went for creating a "runnable" JAR. But in order to run ... a JAR needs a `main()`.

Thus: simply export as "ordinary" JAR. See the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm) for further reading; and follow the instructions for "Creating a New JAR File".

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to create runnable jar file.

To create a normal jar file please follow the steps:

1. In eclipse, right click on the project
2. Select `Export` Search for `JAR file`
3. Select which all the packages needs to be part of JAR file
4. Choose the path where you want export this JAR file & provide the name to JAR file
5. Click `Finish`